# Why did God have to rest?

Tags: nature-of-god, genesis, creation, sabbath

Why did God have to rest on the seventh day of creation ([Genesis 2:1–3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+2%3A1-3&version=NABRE)), if He only had to say a few commandments on each day? Is not the 'rest' borne out of the fact that God did actively participate in the process of creation? What is the Catholic view on such a perspective?